# Set a primitive double member variable to null

Tags: java, type-conversion

So let's say I want to set a member variable to null.

```
MyObject m = new MyObject();
m.setMyNumber(null);
```

Compiler error: Cannot convert null to double.
So I thought of a trick.

```
MyObject m = new MyObject();
Double d = null;
m.setMyNumber(d);
```

Feeling a bit hackish, but compiler didn't throw any error.
Question is, what will happen if I call m.getMyNumber().

Comment: It may compile, but if you run that code, you'll get a NullPointerException, because a primitive variable cannot be set to null.

Comment: It will just return `null` as long as you use the `Double` wrapper object.

Comment: We can't answer this question based on what you've told us. I would expect a runtime error on the `setMyNumber` line in your second example, if I make a reasonable guess at the method signature.

Comment: why dont you post the MyObject class?

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish by setting it to null?

Comment: Yeah, guess I have to box that field in Double object instead of the primitive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This compilation error message implies that `MyObject` holds a `double myNumber` field and not an object : `Double myNumber` field.

But you cannot set a primitive variable with `null`. Only objects may be assigned to `null`.

> Question is, what will happen if I call m.getMyNumber().

You would have not even the time to invoke it.

As soon as `Double d = null; m.setMyNumber(d);` will be executed, a `NullPointerException` will be thrown as `null` cannot be `unboxed` into a `double` value.

The [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.8) references this point :

> 5.1.8. Unboxing Conversion
>
> At run time, unboxing conversion proceeds as follows:
>
> ...
>
> **If r is null, unboxing conversion throws a NullPointerException**

Answer (score 0):

Your code will crash on run time while calling setMyNumber, since there is no way to convert `null` to `double`.

Answer (score 0):

You will get NullPointerException. :)